# First time dedicated server with CPanel

Tags: hosting, centos, cpanel, dedicated

So I got my first dedicated server for my website. Never had dedicated before, I paid the extra $25 to have CPanel installed because that's what I know. I'm really more or less a web designer, this version of CPanel is the root version so I have a very slight clue as to what I'm looking at.

I switched to dedicated because my shared kept shutting me down for having files unrelated to my website but they were relevant to my business, I would put the files up that were too big to e-mail and send out links to my clients so they could download them easily, shared hosting didn't like this, I was told to get dedicated.

Basically I need to transfer my existing website from shared hosting from 1 company to my dedicated server of another company. It looks like what I need to do first is create a new account, tried that, but the directory it forwards to doesn't exist so I some how have to create a directory first? Once I get this, how does DNS work so I can have my domain point to the website? Or do I just somehow point the domain to the server IP? Normally you'd get name servers to setup to your domain, I only have an IP.

I've looked around on google and youtube for information on this CPanel, all I find is CPanel that comes with shared hosting(the one I was used to and knew how to use).

Is there documentation anywhere that gives instructions from start to finish  on how to get your website running on a dedicated server?

I apologize for sounding stupid, just can't find any info on how to get a new account setup in CPanel and get my domain pointed to it because I have an IP and that's it, no name server.

Thanks a bunch
-Mike

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally figured this out for only 1 IP on CPanel/WHM , what you need to do is first go to your domain registar and make 3 sub domains.

server.whateverdomain.com

ns1.whateverdomain.com

ns2.whateverdomain.com

Go to your server and change the hostname to your first subdomain:

server.whateverdomain.com

once that's complete then change your server's name servers to ns1.whateverdomain.com
ns2.whateverdomain.com and assign only ns1.whateverdomain.com an IP address (if you have more than 1 IP address, then assign ns2 as well) Remember what IP address you signed each one.

Go to your registar and now edit:

ns1.whateverdomain.com

ns2.whateverdomain.com

Make sure that you KEEP the registar DNS, only edit the IP of the subdomains, type in the IP address that was assigned to each one, save and let them update. Then edit server.whateverdomain.com and point that to the server's main IP address again keeping the registars DNS.

once that's done, go back into your server and create a new CPanel account for your main domain and select to use your nameservers and NOT your host's name servers.

Once that's done, go back to your registar and edit the DNS and type in the namesevers you've created AKA ns1 and ns2.

There should be no need for you to login as root and use whm anymore unless you need to restart or configure your server. Use the CPanel account that you just created like you used to.

Answer (score 0):

For the name servers you need 2 ip's i.e ns1.domain.com, ns2.domain.com and you set them up in WHM domain.com/whm login as your root user, and select edit setup.

Comment: Ok I'm uploaded a quick screen capture of what I'm seeing.

Comment: http://passsnap.info/forstack1.PNG (passnap.info is just a .info i bought specifically for sharing images, don't mind it lol)

Comment: I went to server configuration and clicked on basic cpanel & WHM setup made a ns1.whatever.com and clicked assign IP address, i only have 1 IP address so it used that one.